# Java OOP; creating array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, static

I'd like to create an array of objects where 3 objects are from one class, and a 4th is from second class.

In the first class I did the following:

```
public class Pupil {
        public int n= 0;

        Pupil(int n) {
            this.n = n;} 
}
```

in the second class I did the following:

```
public class Tutor {
        public int m= 0;

        Tutor(int m) {
            this.m = m;} 
}
```

In the main class, I created several pupil objects and one tutor object, like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //Pupil(n) while for tutor objects it'd be Tutor(m) 
Pupil pupil1 = new Pupil(9);
Pupil pupil2 = new Pupil(8);
Pupil pupil3 = new Pupil(6); 
Tutor tutor1 = new Tutor(2);
```

Using objects for printing in main works fine.

But I'd like to create a fourth class where I group them into arrays of objects, but it won't see the objects that I created to create groups out of them. I'm also not sure about the format for creating an array of objects.

```
public class Groups {

    public static void main(String [] args){



    Pupil [] g1 = {tutor1, pupil1, pupil2, pupil3};
    //cannot resolve any symbols 
    }
}
```

EDIT: according to my tutor the groups class should be static to solve this, but I'm not sure how to actually code this?

Edit2: an answer pointed that the array should be Object as the above code would only be able to create an array of pupils, not pupils and tutors objects.

```
Object [] g1 = {tutor1, pupil1, pupil2, pupil3};
```

but that still doesn't solve the main issue where no objects are seen from the groups class (//cannot resolve any symbols)

Comment: Is there any relation between `Pupil` and `Tutor` ?

Comment: @AhmedHENTETI I've edited the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays can only contain the same type of object. With that being said, here is a way:

```
Object[] g1 = {tutor1, pupil1, pupil2, pupil3};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get the difference between my declaration and this?

Comment: You are declaring an array of `Pupil`s and trying to put tutors and pupils inside it. You can't do that because tutors are not pupils. They are different. They have only one thing in common, and that is: they are both `Object`. You have to declare an array of `Object` to put them in the same array.

Comment: Fair enough, but the groups class still doesn't see any objects to create an array out of them.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: For example, in each object in the declaration of the array I am getting the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'pupil1'" , which means that the groups class can't see them.

Comment: Because you didn't declare them in `Groups`. You declared them in `Main`.

Comment: Alright, but is it possible to go around this without creating them in groups? I'd like to use a different class than groups for testing the groups (in this case, main) and I'm getting the same error when I declare them in groups anyway, but this time in main.

Comment: You can write getters. https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp

Comment: I believe I answered you original question. Please mark as answer. If you have more questions open another one.

Comment: Your addition about the Object array is very appreciated, but the main question was clearly defined by "//cannot resolve any symbols" to be the resolving issue.

Comment: If you want to test `Groups` in `Main` what you should be doing is this: delete the `main` method in `Groups`, declare your array as a field in `Groups`, create an instance of `Groups` in `main` of `Main`. Now you can do whatever you want with `Groups` in `Main`.

Comment: I believe you know what object instances, constructors and fields are. If you don't, you should read the corresponding chapter in your book, or watch a YouTube tutorial on those things.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed programming language so you cannot add different type objects to a same collection. But you take advantage of OPP polymorphism principle. You can create a parent class and extend your subclasses from parent class.

**Parent Class**

```java
public class Group {
}
```

**Child Classes**

```java
public class Pupil extends Group {

    public int m = 0;

    public Pupil(int m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

}
```

```java
public class Tutor extends Group {

    public int n = 0;

    public Tutor(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

}
```

So this way you can use it as follows:

```java
public class TestSchool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pupil pupil1 = new Pupil(9);
        Pupil pupil2 = new Pupil(8);
        Pupil pupil3 = new Pupil(6);
        Tutor tutor1 = new Tutor(2);
        Tutor tutor2 = new Tutor(2);

        Group[] groupArray = {pupil1, pupil2, pupil3, tutor1, tutor2};
    }
}
```